# Trying to make a for loop that divides by 3

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get numbers that are only divided by 3 so im not sure why I'm getting 0 as well. Here's my code:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `numbers[i] % 3 === 0` `<--` that's the solution `(-:`

Comment: You are checking the index (which ranges from 0-9), and not the number in the array (which range from 1-10). Perhaps you mean to use `numbers[i] % 3` and `console.log(numbers[i])` instead?

Comment: ah that was it, cheers man

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to filter, so you don't have to worry about indexes.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(
  numbers.filter(function(number){ return number % 3 === 0; })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't iterating over the list. You're iterating over a range of numbers, 0-9. Change your `if` statement to

`if (numbers[i] % 3 == 0) {`

so you are actually getting the numbers from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you did wrong, because you have to use `numbers[i]`.
Let's see the better way

```
const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const correctNumbers = numbers.filter(n => !(n % 3));

console.log(correctNumbers); // [3, 6, 9]
```